How to add a header to a google doc using google app script
I have a google doc consisting of both portrait and landscape pages. I want to have a header in each page. The header will have a single line with the document name ("Test Document") left alighted and the date right aligned. When the document is downloaded as a docx, the alignment should be properly displayed. How can I achieve this with google app script?

Issue and workaround:
About The header will have a single line with the document name ("Test Document") left alighted and the date right aligned., when the tab stop is used for the paragraph, this can be simply achieved. But, unfortunately, in the current stage, the property tabStops for managing the tab stop for the paragraph is read-only for Docs API. Ref Also, this cannot also be managed with Document service (DocumentApp). This might be resolved in a future update.
From this situation, in this answer, as a workaround, your goal is achieved using a table.
The sample script is as follows.
Sample script:
Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of the Google Document and save the script.
function myFunction() {
  // Retrieve headers.
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  let heads = [doc.getHeader()];
  if (heads[0]) {
    heads = [];
    const document = doc.getBody().getParent();
    let s = null;
    while (s = document.findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.HEADER_SECTION, s)) {
      heads.push(s.getElement().asHeaderSection());
    }
  } else {
    heads = [doc.addHeader()];
  }

  // Set text and text alignment.
  const docName = doc.getName();
  const date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
  heads.forEach(h => {
    const t = h.clear().insertTable(1, [[docName, date]]).setBorderWidth(0);
    t.getCell(0, 0).getChild(0).asParagraph().setAttributes({ [DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT]: DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.LEFT });
    t.getCell(0, 1).getChild(0).asParagraph().setAttributes({ [DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT]: DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT });
  });
}

Testing:
When this script is run, the following result is obtained.

When this script is run, the table is created by including 2 cells for a single row. And, the document name and the date are put into each cell (from your question). And, the text alignments for each cell are set. By this, your goal is achieved.
Note:

In this modification, even when the header has already existed and "Different first page" for the header is checked, the script works.
Unfortunately, from your question, I couldn't confirm the date format. So, I used the sample format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss. Please modify this to your expected format.
If you want to keep the existing header text, please modify const t = h.clear().insertTable(1, [[docName, date]]).setBorderWidth(0) to const t = h.insertTable(1, [[docName, date]]).setBorderWidth(0).

References:

ParagraphStyle of Document for Google Docs API
formatDate(date, timeZone, format)


Thank you Tanaike for the detailed answer. I tried your proposed solution and in google docs, the alignment is correct for both portrait and landscape pages. But when I download as docx, there in landscape pages the right alignment is not to the most right of the page. It is somewhere in the middle

@Kalpa Welivitigoda Thank you for replying. From I tried your proposed solution and in google docs, the alignment is correct for both portrait and landscape pages., I confirmed that my script worked.

@Kalpa Welivitigoda About your new issue But when I download as docx, there in landscape pages the right alignment is not to the most right of the page. It is somewhere in the middle, when I tested my script and exported the document as DOCX, unfortunately, the document name and the date were aligned to the left and the right. I cannot replicate It is somewhere in the middle. I apologize for this situation. But, I would like to support you. So, in order to correctly replicate your situation, can you provide a sample document for replicating it? By this, I would like to confirm it.

@Kalpa Welivitigoda When I tested several times using several documents, I confirmed that when the document was exported as DOCX, there was a case where the check of "Link to previous" was unchecked under a document mixed the portrait and landscape pages. Because of this, the header is not correctly shown. Although I'm not sure whether this is related to your situation, I guessed that this might be a bug. I thought that this situation might be required to be reported to the Google issue tracker because I couldn't find the same reports.

@Kalpa Welivitigoda As additional information, I confirmed that when the document mixed the portrait and landscape pages is exported as a PDF file, the headers of all pages are correctly shown. And, I confirmed that when the PDF file is manually converted to DOCX by the online site, the converted DOCX has the correct headers for all pages. From this result, I guessed that the issue of directly converting from Google Documents to DOCX is a bug. Also, the above conversion might be a current workaround for obtaining DOCX with the correct headers.


Open Google Apps Script:
In your Google Doc, go to Extensions > Apps Script to open the Google Apps Script editor.

Create a New Script:
Delete any existing code and start with a fresh script.

Set Up the Header Code:
Copy and paste the following code to create a header in your Google Doc:


Code:-
function addHeader() {

        // Open the active Google Doc

        const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  
        // Access the header section

        const header = doc.addHeader();
  
        // Add text or any other elements to the header

        header.appendParagraph("Your Header Text 
        Here").setFontSize(14).setBold(true);
     }


Run the Script:
Click the Run button in the Apps Script editor.
If this is your first time running the script, grant any necessary permissions.

Check Your Document:
The script will add a header with the specified text and styling to the document.

Customize as Needed:
Modify the appendParagraph() text, font size, or style to suit your needs.



Thanks Arjun, any clue on how to set the alignments?

you can use the Paragraph.setAlignment() method and you can add also in the code like this:-
const headerText = header.appendParagraph("Your Header Text Here")
.setFontSize(14)
.setBold(true)
.setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
// Alignment options: LEFT, CENTER, RIGHT

May be my wording was misleading. I want to have a single line with two different text segments, one left aligned (left tab) and the other right aligned (right tab).
